# django double "extends", problem with login

Tags: python, django, authentication

Hi:) I have got a small problem with template double extends system. I have got a scheme:

```
base.html ---> index.html ---> something.html
```

When I log in to the site I have got access to all invisible blocks (invisible blocks for anonymous users) like:

```
{% if user.is_superuser %}
   blabla
{% endif %}
```

So "blabla" **is visible** for me, because I am a superuser and I'm logged in. It works fine in base.html, index.html but it **doesn't work** in something.html. Why?? Simple it looks like user: 'superuser' is log out.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem extending twice. I think you need to show us your code for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you passing the request [context](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1) to render_to_response (or HttpResponse)?
Information about logged in user must be stored in the context ([see documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1)), and you have to do it explicitly.
Generic views automatically do it, but if you are using your own view for something.html, with a direct call to render_to_response, then you do not have information about the user.

Therefore, the code in the view should look something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def my_personalized_view(request):
  return render_to_response('something.html',
                             {},
                             context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```